# Compiling static Qt with openSSL errors

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, openssl, static-linking

I successfully compiled OpenSSL 1.0.1 under win32 with mingw. Now I'm trying to compile static Qt 4.8.1 with following config:

`configure -release -static -qt-zlib -nomake examples -nomake demos -no-qt3support -no-scripttools -no-opengl -no-webkit -no-phonon -no-style-motif -no-style-cde -no-style-cleanlooks -no-style-plastique -no-sql-sqlite -openssl-linked OPENSSL_LIBS="-lssl -lcrypto -lgdi32 -luser32" -I H:\Workplace\OpenSSL\include -L H:\Workplace\OpenSSL`

I got these errors:

`H:\Workplace\OpenSSL/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:(.text+0x17be): undefined ref
erence to '_time32'` (several times)

`H:\Workplace\OpenSSL/libcrypto.a(o_time.o):o_time.c:(.text+0x362): undefined ref
erence to '_gmtime32'`

`H:\Workplace\OpenSSL/libcrypto.a(mem_dbg.o):mem_dbg.c:(.text+0x4c7): undefined r
eference to '_localtime32'`

**SOLVED (see below)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved all problems, here is full solution to compile **static Qt** with **static OpenSSL** using **TDM-GCC**.

- Download sources of latest OpenSSL and unpack them.
- I used TDM-GCC to compile, so download and install it.
- Install MSYS.
- Create file `../MsysInstallDir/etc/fstab` with the following content:

`MyPathToMinGW      /mingw` (REQUIRED if you use tdm-gcc)

`MyPathToPerl       /perl` (perl is also required to be installed)

- to compile OpenSSL run the following commands in OpenSSL sources folder (in MSYS):

`./config`

`make`

- download qt-everywhere (I used v.4.8.1) sources and unpack them.

***UPDATE:** Recently I built 4.8.2 on another windows7 computer and got compiling error (while building my app): «cannot find -lQtCore4», «cannot find -lQtGui4». Here is the solution that helped me - edit file "qt-sources-dir/mkspecs/win32-g++/qmake.conf". Set `QMAKE_LFLAGS = -static -static-libgcc`*

- create conf.bat file in qt sources dir with config:

`configure -release -static -qt-zlib -nomake examples -nomake demos -no-qt3support -no-scripttools -no-opengl -no-webkit -no-phonon -no-style-motif -no-style-cde -no-sql-sqlite -openssl OPENSSL_LIBS="-lssl -lcrypto -lgdi32 -luser32" -I MyOpenSSLdir\include -L MyOpenSSLdir`

- run `cmd`. run `mingwvars.bat` in mingw folder. run `conf.bat` in qt sources folder (or add sources folder to the PATH and run it from another directory, to separate install from sources). It will take a few hours to compile Qt.
- add to project's .pro file: `INCLUDEPATH += OpenSSLdir/include/`

I think it may help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you need -openssl-linked? We always build Qt with dynamic usage of openssl. (-openssl)

Comment: yes, I need it. I want to have my .exe without dependency on libeay and libssl.

Comment: Although I should try it, because before that I tried to compile qt with installed openssl, now it's compiled with mingw..

Comment: with -openssl-linked openssl will be required and application will not start without it. But if you use -openssl flag - qt try to load openssl synamicaly and if it can't be loaded - doesn't use it at all (in this case application will run but if you use ssl sockets (for example) - they wouldn't work).

Comment: If I try `-openssl-linked`, I run into this problem https://forum.qt.io/topic/107364/static-compile-qt-5-13-1-with-openssl-1-1-1d-using-mingw-in-windows-10. Only `-ssl -openssl` has worked for me.